# Flutter web: How to add image from firestore to a PDF file using pdf package

Tags: firebase, flutter

I repost  this question because I didn't find the solution till now . please help

original Califa [Flutter web: Add image from Firebase Storage to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817351/flutter-web-add-image-from-firebase-storage-to-pdf)

I want to create a pdf within a flutter web app which includes images from firebase storage. I use the PDF package.

For asset images, my code is as follows:

final tbLogo = pw.MemoryImage(
(await rootBundle.load('assets/images/myImage.png'))
.buffer
.asUint8List(),
);

then I add it to the pdf:
pw.Image(tbLogo, height: 50.0),

how to do the same thing from firebase storage, in flutter web I use :

Future downloadUrl(String photoUrl) {
return fb
.storage()
.refFromURL('gs://xxxx.appspot.com')
.child(photoUrl)
.getDownloadURL();
}

and

```
 StreamBuilder<Uri>(
                  stream: _abonneCommController
                      .downloadUrl(aboncom.abonPhoto)
                      .asStream(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    return Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.transparent,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                          child: Container(
                            // height: 100,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                            child: CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 40.0,
                              backgroundImage:
                                  NetworkImage(snapshot.data.toString()),
                              backgroundColor: lightGrey,
                              child: (!snapshot.hasData)
                                  ? Text(
                                      '50 Kilobyte',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 14,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    )
                                  : null,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        OutlinedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            _abonneCommController
                                .uploadAbonneCommImageToStorage(
                                    curentuser.id, aboncom.commId);
                          },
                          child: Text('Update'),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
```

But how to do in pdf file that display the same image from firestore

Thanks